# If every vertex of a graph G has degree 2, then G is a cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

I know that the statement is False. Because a graph can be a disconnected graph with each component a cycle. But I am unable to construct a graph for a counterexample of the above statement. Can any one give me the answer with an example.

Comment: Well with the reasoning you've just given, can't you just use a counterexample with two components, each with three vertices in a cycle?

Comment: Yes with three vertices in a cycle.